# How to cache XmlTextWriter data?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, xml

I have a page where I'm just writing a bunch of XML data to the screen. It's making several database calls to get all the data:

```
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(Response.OutputStream, Encoding.UTF8);
writer.WriteStartDocument();

writer.WriteStartElement("rss");
writer.WriteAttributeString("version", "2.0");

writer.WriteStartElement("channel");
writer.WriteElementString("title", "MyTitle");
writer.WriteElementString("link", "http://www.mysite.com/");

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM vwXMLFeedData", conn);

    conn.Open();

    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("item");
            writer.WriteElementString("title", rdr["Title"].ToString());
            writer.WriteElementString("link", rdr["URL"].ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
}

writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.WriteEndDocument();
writer.Close();
```

I'd like to cache all that XML data so that I don't need to make a database call every time, but I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing it with the XmlTextWriter. What's the best strategy here?

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextWriter()`. It's been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to cache it in memory, then create a `MemoryStream` and write into it.  So your code to initialize the writer would become:

```
MemoryStream CacheStream = new MemoryStream();
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(CacheStream, Encoding.UTF8);
```

The code to populate the stream remains the same, except before you close the writer, you'll need to save the stream's buffer and the size:

```
writer.Flush();
long CachedDataSize = CacheStream.Position;
byte[] CachedData = CacheStream.Buffer;
writer.Close();
```

Or, if you want to cache to a file, simply create a `FileStream` and write the XML to it.

In either case, you then read from the cached data whenever you want to send info to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that instead of trying to figure out how to cache XmlTextWriter, you instead look at it another way.

For example, you could write to a temporary location, and then serve subsequent requests from that location.

You'll need to figure out how to detect if the cached data is old or not.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing out to the `Response.OutputStream`, use a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) - you can convert this into a cached string and then output that to the `OutputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for - a way to avoid making a database call - primarily implies caching the *database results*, not the XmlTextWriter output.

How you cache these results is up to you.  If there is really only one rendering of those db query results - that is to say, if you use the results only to emit the XML, and then do nothing else with those results - then caching the XML output is equivalent to caching the database query results directly.

One way to cache only the results is to do something like this:

```
private Dictionary<String,String> cache;
private void FillCache()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM vwXMLFeedData", conn);

        conn.Open();
        cache = new Dictionary<String,String>();
        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                cache.Add(rdr["Title"].ToString(), rdr["URL"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then, when it comes time to render the XML:

```
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(Response.OutputStream, Encoding.UTF8);
writer.WriteStartDocument();

writer.WriteStartElement("rss");
writer.WriteAttributeString("version", "2.0");

writer.WriteStartElement("channel");
writer.WriteElementString("title", "MyTitle");
writer.WriteElementString("link", "http://www.mysite.com/");
if (cache==null)
    FillCache();

foreach (var kvp in  cache)
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("item");
    writer.WriteElementString("title", kvp.Key);
    writer.WriteElementString("link", kvp.Value);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}

writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.WriteEndDocument();
writer.Close();
```